# Default mode network's function in information consolidation?

Tags: neuroscience

I remember seeing a lot of research about this a few years back, suggesting replaying memory's during wakeful rest might help long term memory retention, although it was inconclusive.

I was wondering if there is a prevailing opinion on whether the DMN plays a significant role in information consolidation.

I found points arguing that idle/resting times serve functions of processing new inputs into our idea of the world (1) and information/memory consolidation (2). The problem is that these studies tend to be older and are usually mentioned as tangent points and so I was very interested in whether the current prevailing opinion about time spent where the DMN dominant does serve an important function for well-being.

Especially because it seems quite prevalent in pop culture science to say that the DMN is a "dragon we need to slay" and turning it off is the goal to a better life. A lot of that bases itself on a Harvard study that found a positive relationship between mental well-being and less time the DMN is activated.

> (1) The Importance of Rest and Sleep: Maintaining Balance Is Key You
> need to modulate expending physical energy with taking time to rest,
> reflect, and recharge. Scientc American noted that research pub-lished
> in 2012 by researchers from the University of Southern California and
> MIT argued that "when we are resting the brain is anything but idle
> and that, far from being purposeless or unproductive, downtime is in
> fact essential to mental processes that affirm our identities, develop
> our understanding of human behavior and instill an internal code of
> ethics." These processes may depend on the brain circuit that kicks in
> when people are in a kind of daydreaming, resting state—a circuit
> brain researchers call the default mode network.

https://books.google.se/books?id=WeRhDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22a+circuit+brain+researchers+call+the+default+mode+network.%22&source=bl&ots=xXAkcCnYHF&sig=ACfU3U2dLCWtfcN51Ivy_OcRIb79SrpPAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO8buWm473AhUFSvEDHecWCGEQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22a%20circuit%20brain%20researchers%20call%20the%20default%20mode%20network.%22&f=false

> (2) More recent theories propose that fundamental intrinsic processes
> such as information consolidation and stabilization may be related to
> activity in default mode regions [13–15].
> https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3134578/

Thanks a lot for your time!